# Check nodejs V8 arguments

Tags: node.js, arguments, v8

Is there an elegant way to detect the flags passed to the node runtime in code?

```bash
node --no-opt app.js
```

I'm trying to detect if the `--no-opt` option was passed in.

Unfortunately `process.argv` doesn't work and [v8](https://nodejs.org/api/v8.html) doesn't seem to be giving any information either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is another field on process that we can check

```js
process.execArgv.includes('--no-opt')
```